# How to get customer's uploaded file through gravity forms.

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I need to get the attachment files from upload file feature provided in Gravity forms. 
E.g. I have asked the user to send the scanned copy of their resume using Gravityforms upload feature. It's working fine but I need to know where gravity forms is storing the files? (Pathinfo).

Answer (score 0):

It's the physical files are the wp-content folder under uploads. You can also change the default path using the `gform_upload_path` function. https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_upload_path/

However you can get the exact link from the entry management / entry details page.